# Ativar e desativar alarmes do Android via código

Tags: java, android

Estou criando uma aplicação e em determinada parte irei necessitar que o aplicativo ative e desative alarmes (do próprio celular). Procurei na internet mas não encontrei nada que me ajudasse no descrito. Não sei quais classes ou biblioteca podem ser usados e se é realmente possível.

Comment: A que alarmes se refere?

Comment: Como já dito "[...] ative e desative alarmes (do próprio celular)"

Comment: O que são *"alarmes (do próprio celular)"*?

Comment: Os alarmes que vem em um app "de fabrica", que já vem junto com o celular. Me refiro aos despertador, quando digo alarme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não tem como fazer isso. Não tem nem como você pegar a lista de todos alarmes ativos no sistema, por exemplo. A não ser que o app que iniciou o alarme forneça servicos para tal, usando ContentProvider por exemplo.

O que você pode fazer é usar o *Do not disturb*. Quando o seu app iniciar, você lança uma intent ativando o *dnd* e quando fechar lanca uma desativando.

Esse link pode te ajudar na implementacao https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31862753/android-how-to-turn-on-do-not-disturb-dnd-programmatically

Lembrando que você vai ter que, dependendo da versao do android(6.0+), pedir permissão ao usuario para usar esse serviço.